# Scala Akka how to create a Typed ActorContext in route

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

I am pretty new in Scala Akka . Say I am spawning a `Configuration` child actor,

```
object Configuration {
 
  def apply(): Behavior[ConfigurationMessage] = Behaviors.setup(context => new Configuration(context))
 
}
```

Now I need same context `ActorContext[ConfigurationMessage]` in my HTTP router to do some operation.

How can I create the same `ActorContext` there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ActorContext` cannot be used outside of the actor it's associated with, including in an HTTP router.  Any `ActorContext` which leaks out of an actor (e.g. by sending it as a message) will, by design, throw an exception and not do anything for most operations if it's used outside of its actor.

The only operations on the `ActorContext` which could possibly be used outside of the associated actor are:

- `context.ask` and friends can be just as easily replaced with a `Future`-returning `ask` on the target `RecipientRef` with the message send occurring in a `foreach` callback on the future.
- `context.executionContext`: can just as easily use `system.executionContext` (which will typically be the same) or by looking up via dispatchers
- `context.pipeToSelf` is probably best done as a send in a `foreach` callback on the future
- `context.scheduleOnce` is better done using the system scheduler directly
- `context.self` is kind of pointless, as you'd have to have the `ActorRef` already in order to leak the `ActorContext`
- `context.system` is likewise pointless, as you already have the system

Comment: Very well explained , thank you